# How can I make a Kivy (KVlang) cascaded spinner set respond to my first on_release?

Tags: events, event-handling, kivy

My cascaded spinners do what i want on the SECOND release of the master spinner.

How can i make this work on the FIRST release?

Thanks in advance. Here is my KVlang and Python code.

KVlang:

```
# 0009_spinnerCascade.kv
<MyLayout@BoxLayout>:  
    orientation: 'vertical'    

    Spinner:  
        id: s1    
        text: 'colors'
        values: 'colors numbers days'.split()
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        my_string_property: 'hello from s1'
        on_release: s2.my_key = self.text

    Label:
        text: 'Mid label'

    Spinner:
        id: s2
        text: 'choose one'
        my_dict:  {'colors': 'red green blue'.split(), 'numbers': '1 2 3'.split(), 'days':'mon tue wed'.split() }
        my_key: 'numbers'
        values: self.my_dict[self.my_key] 
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'           

MyLayout
```

Python

```
''' 0009_spinnerCascade.py

'''
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width',  '430')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '430')

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('0009_spinnerCascade.kv')
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`release` event is triggered when your spinner opens and shows options, before you select any. In that moment value of `s2.my_key` is set to `s1.text`. After you select option, `release` event is not triggered and `s2.my_key` remains unchanged. Then after you display list of `s1` options with second click, second `release` event is triggered and value od `s2.my_key` is finally setted to right value. Observe this behaviour with:

```
<MyLayout@BoxLayout>:  
    # ...  
    Spinner:  
        id: s1    
        # ...
        on_release: s2.my_key = self.text ; print("spinner opened")

    # ...
```

You actually need to observe `text` property to detect changes:

```
<MyLayout@BoxLayout>:  
    # ...  

    Spinner:  
        id: s1    
        # ...  
        on_text: s2.my_key = self.text ; print("option selected")

    # ...
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how this would be implemented in Python without using the .kv file?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this behaviour as follows:

```
def callback(instance,value):
    print(instance,value)

class spinnerName(Spinner):
    values = ('1','2','3')

spinInstance = Spinner()
spinInstance.bind(text=callback)
```

print(instance,value) will be called every time you click an item in the Spinner.